# Is it a good practice creating state in React component without changing it ever?

Tags: reactjs

If there are some strings/objects/arrays that contain data needed for a component (like categories) and that data doesn't have to be changed at all, would it be better to create a state or to place it in another file that is not a component and import it from there?

Comment: No. State is for values that change over time. You can import it from another file, or make it a static property or const. Read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) from the docs for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a `constants` directory and have all "constants" living in there

then import them into your components where you need them

example usage

```
export const HELLO = 'hello'
export const GREETINGS = { hello: 'hello', goodbye: 'goodbye' }
```

then in your component

```
import { HELLO } from 'constants/hello'
import { GREETINGS } from 'constants/greetings'

<div> {HELLO} </div>
<div> {GREETINGS.hello} </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[From this article](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/understanding-the-fundamentals-of-state-in-react-79c711be677f):

> **What is State?**
>
> State is a JavaScript object that stores a component’s dynamic data and determines the component’s behaviour. Because state is dynamic, it enables a component to keep track of changing information in between renders and for it to be dynamic and interactive.

Then creating state without changing it's a bad practice because state must be dynamic.

Comment: If you took a portion of your answer form the link provided, you should signal it by putting it in quotes.

Comment: @BrianThompson i don't know how i can add quotes, this is why i added the link below ,I just wanted to help

Comment: Its no problem, I'm also just trying to help. You can use `>` in front of each line like I did in the edit. You can also find more markdown syntax help by clicking the question mark icon in the top right of the editor